# How to find log2 of a number with Newton's method?

Tags: calculus, approximation, newton-raphson

I am learning C++ and I find `pow`, `log`, `log2`, `exp` functions provided by `cmath` extremely slow, so that I would like to implement faster versions of them.

I currently have a version using polynomial approximations, which is much faster than the ones provided by the library and very accurate, but not as accurate as the library ones.

I wrote another version using lookup tables, it takes less than a nanosecond to complete and is by far the fastest, and it is also the least accurate:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

vector<double> log2_double() {
    int lim = 1 << 24;
    vector<double> table(lim);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < lim; i++) {
        table[i] = log2(i << 29) - 1075;
    }
    return table;
}
const vector<double> LOG2_DOUBLE = log2_double();

inline double fast_log2_double(double d) {
    uint64_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(d);
    uint64_t e = (bits >> 52) & 0x7ff;
    uint64_t m = bits & 0xfffffffffffff;
    return (e == 0 ? LOG2_DOUBLE[m >> 28] : e + LOG2_DOUBLE[(m | 0x10000000000000) >> 29]);
}
```

However it is really fast, and accurate to 6 decimal digits, so I would like to refine the value using Newton's method:

```
fast_log2(3.1415927f) = 1.651496887207031 : 0.32501220703125 nanoseconds
log2f(3.1415927f) = 1.651496171951294 : 33.90207290649414 nanoseconds
```

Newton's method from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):

$$
x_{n+1}=x_{n}-{\frac {f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}}
$$

Derivative of $\log_2(x)$:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\log_2(x) = \frac{1}{x \cdot \ln(2)}
$$

$\ln(2)$ is a constant, and the derivative is simple to compute.

The equation I am trying to solve is $\log_2(x_0) - x = 0$, a simple function is $f(x) = 2^x - x_0$.

Putting it all together:

$$
x_{n + 1} = x_{n} - (2^{x_n} - x_0) \cdot x_n \cdot \ln(2)
$$

I tried it in Python and it diverges:

```
import numpy as np

LOG2_DOUBLE = np.arange(1 << 24, dtype=np.uint64)
LOG2_DOUBLE = np.log2(LOG2_DOUBLE << 29) - 52
LN2 = np.log(2)

def fast_log2(f: float, lim: int) -> float:
    m, e = f.hex().split("p")
    e = int(e)
    m = int(m[4:], 16)
    l = LOG2_DOUBLE[m >> 28] if not e else e + LOG2_DOUBLE[(m | 0x10000000000000) >> 29]
    for _ in range(lim):
        l = l - (2 ** l - f) * l * LN2
    return l
```

```
In [839]: n = np.random.random()

In [840]: n
Out[840]: 0.14112379908067973

In [841]: np.log2(n)
Out[841]: -2.8249667907196945

In [842]: fast_log2(n, 0)
Out[842]: -2.824966918629066

In [843]: fast_log2(n, 16)
Out[843]: -2.82496890252251

In [844]: fast_log2(n, 128)
Out[844]: -99.49155122185653
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The Newton-method does not always work. But in this case , I am surprised that there are problems. By the way : $34$ nano-seconds is still extremely fast. How accurate is this result ?

Comment: In your iteretive scheme: $x_{n+1} = x_n - (2^{x_n}-x_0)\cdot (x_n\ln(2))$, it seems that you use a function $f(x) = 2^x-x_0$; then, the derivative of $f(x)$, $f'(x) = 2^x\ln(2)$. 

So your scheme shuold be: $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{2^{x_n}-x_0}{2^{x_n}\ln(2)}$.

Comment: Without underestimating your efforts, I'm really surprised that you found something that easy while entire groups of mathematicians and software engineers didn't think about it.

Comment: @Eugene That fixed the problem, and I have reached the maximum precision possible in just two iterations of Newton's method. Please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Dominique Maybe , they were afraid of the possibility that the method might fail for some inputs. So , a proof that it always works would be nice.

Comment: @Dominique there are always a lot of tradeoffs between speed and precision guarantee in transcendent functions calculations, and this implementation could make different call from what OP did (and it's not even be guaranteed to be optimal in any sense).

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Table of 128MB could cause perf issues in real apps. FWIW, I measure 10.9ns for `log2(double)` vs 1.8ns for `fast_log2_double(double)` with ten year old hardware and software (Xeon E3-1270 V2, Intel C/C++ compiler 13.1.3.198). `log2(double)` is accurate to 0.51 ulps. `const int N=1000000000;double x,sum;printf("x: ");scanf("%lg",&x);printf("x=%23.16e\n",x);for(int k=0;k<3;k++){start=second();for(int i=0;i<N;i++){sum+=/*fast_log2_double(x);*/log2(x);}stop=second();}elapsed=stop-start;printf("sum=%15.8e\n",sum);printf("elapsed = %15.8e sec, %15.8e sec per log2\n",elapsed,elapsed/N);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your iterative scheme:

$$
_{n+1} = _n−(2^{x_n}−_0)⋅(x_n\ln(2)), 
$$

you use a function $f(x) = 2^x-x_0$. Then, the derivative of $f(x)$ is

$$
f'(x) = 2^x\ln(2),
$$

Which means that your iterative scheme should be:

$$
x_{n+1} = x_n−\frac{2^{x_n}−_0}{2^{x_n}\ln(2)}.
$$